# Grab coordinates using Bing Location API and use it to create interactive map

Tags: javascript, json, bing-maps

Would like to:

1. Grab the coordinates of an (Australian) address using the locations API,
2. with the coordinates, create interactive/non-static version like in 
   http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7

Or is there an better way to get a non-static Bing map using their latest REST services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured, it was already on the page http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7! 
Within the section ***REST services - find a location by query***...

Instead of coordinates, I can pass in the full address by the query variable.

(The implementation is a lot more elaborate than the static-map image URL using http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/Road/)

Comment: If there is an easier way where it can be retrieved as an image URL, please post.